# How to dynamically add links to shapes and download the corresponding CSV file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a link like this "https://example.com.uk/Download/Report/2017-10-01_successful.csv", and I am unable to download the CSV file.

I have to change the date every day through this link to download the CSV file. So, I tried the following code where a, b, and c are the given inputs for a specific date.

**My requirements are:**

I want to download this report by changing the date value inside the link. My code adds the links but unable to download data.

What do I have to do? Are there any libraries need to be referenced in Excel VBA?

**Here's my code:**

```
Sub Macro2()

    Range("D14:L14").Select
    Sheets("RAW_DATA").Select
    Range("B26").Select

    a = 2017
    b = 10
    c = 3
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 11")).Select
    'Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:= _
        "https://example.com.uk/Download/Report/" & a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "_successful.csv"
    Range("D20").Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "https://example.com.uk/Download/Report/" & a & "-" & b & "-" & c & "_successful.csv"
    ActiveWindow.Visible = False
    Windows("2017-10-01_successful.csv").Visible = True
    'Windows("ARC_ASC_TEMPLATE_VBA_V3.xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work what happens instead?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim wb As Workbook, fName, a, b, c

    a = 2017
    b = 10
    c = 3

    fName = "https://example.com.uk/Download/Report/" & a & "-" & _
            Format(b, "00") & "-" & Format(c, "00") & "_successful.csv"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fName)

    Debug.Print wb.Name

End Sub
```